# If $m$ and $n$ are measures, is $m-n$ also a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I already proved that $m+n$ is a measure, but I'm not sure if that implies that $m-n$ is a measure since $-n$ is not a measure. Or maybe I shouldn't see $m-n$ as $m+(-n)$, and only define it as $(m-n)(A)=m(A)-n(A)$ (I think my proof works if I see it that way, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Well, in general, if $m(A)\ge n(A)$ for all $A$, then it will give a positive measure. However, there are real or complex valued measures as well (e.g. $A\mapsto \int_Af(z)dz$ for a fixed complex function and $A\subseteq\Bbb C$ Borel..)

Comment: Difference of measures may be a [signed measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure). But the usual assumption is that at least one of the measures is finite, to avoid indterminate form $\infty-\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enterprise is fraught with hazards. If $m$ and $n$ are finite measures, then $m-n$ is a signed measure.  You get into problems when you have a set $E$ so $m(E) = n(E) = +\infty$.